# Capture image in maya 2017 viewport2.0, in python

Tags: python, maya

I try to capture an image of my Maya 3d  viewport2.0, and didn't manage to save anything:
here is the code :

```
#Import api modules
import maya.OpenMaya as api
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI

#Grab the last active 3d viewport
view = apiUI.M3dView.active3dView()

#read the color buffer from the view, and save the MImage to disk
image = api.MImage()
#view.readColorBuffer(image, True)     #Doesn't work because of viewport2 
if view.getRendererName() == view.kViewport2Renderer:      
    image.create(view.portWidth(), view.portHeight(), 4, api.MImage.kFloat)
    view.readColorBuffer(image)
    image.convertPixelFormat(api.MImage.kByte)
    print "viewPort2"
else:
    view.readColorBuffer(image)
    print "old viewport !"
image.writeToFile('C:/test.png', 'png')
```

I get error message :
// Error: Failed to open output file: C:/test.png //
// Error: (kFailure): Unexpected Internal Failure

What did I miss ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated !
Fabrice

Comment: Did you try save your file in a different folder, instead than root? By default Windows won't let you create files directly in `C:` (unless you disabled UAC already)

Comment: Great thanks mapofemergence ! That was as simple as that ! Replacing with 'V:/test.png' do the job !

Comment: @Fabrice
If I run the script on 4-views(e.g top, left, front, persp), it makes the image of another view that is not in current. It only works on single view in my case. It bothers me for years.

Comment: @hyun-geun-kim, Sorry for the late reply; same here; I don't know how to choose the window I want on 4-views.